# Mostrar div en base a combinacion de Opciones seleccionadas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy tratando de mostrar diferentes DIVs en base a la selección de 2 'option' pero si quiero mostrar 2 veces el mismo div con diferentes 'option' no se muestran.

## div1 = 3+5 (no se muestra)

## div2 = 2+7 (se muestra)

## div1 = 4+4 (se muestra)

¿Por qué?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ex589b9/

```js
var $s1 = $('#select1').change(change);
var $s2 = $('#select2').change(change);

function change(){
    $('#div1').toggle($s1.val() == '3' && $s2.val() == '5')
    $('#div2').toggle($s1.val() == '2' && $s2.val() == '7')
    $('#div1').toggle($s1.val() == '4' && $s2.val() == '4')
    
    
};
```

```css
#div1,#div2,#div3 ,#div4,#div5,#div6,#div7{ display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
<option selected disabled>Valor 1</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>4</option>

</select>
+
<select id="select2">
<option selected disabled>Valor 2</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>4</option>

</select>

<div id="div1">8</div>
<div id="div2">9</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que se esta evaluado la última linea donde defines el div, por ejemplo, aquí :

```
$('#div2').toggle($s1.val() == '4' && $s2.val() == '7')
$('#div1').toggle($s1.val() == '3' && $s2.val() == '5')
$('#div2').toggle($s1.val() == '2' && $s2.val() == '7')
$('#div1').toggle($s1.val() == '4' && $s2.val() == '4')
```

únicamente se evaluaría:

```
$('#div2').toggle($s1.val() == '2' && $s2.val() == '7')
$('#div1').toggle($s1.val() == '4' && $s2.val() == '4')
```

Si deseas mostrar y ocultar tus div te recomiendo en este caso usar el método `.show()` y `.hide()`, ya que con `toggle()`, podrías tener algo de problemas al controlar los estados de los `div`. Realiza un cambio en tu script, realizando las evaluaciones de los valores dentro de un `if`:

```
var $s1 = $('#select1').change(change);
var $s2 = $('#select2').change(change);

function change(){

 if(($s1.val() == '3' && $s2.val() == '5') ||    ($s1.val() == '4' && $s2.val() == '4')) {
     $('#div1').show();
 }else if($s1.val() == '2' && $s2.val() == '7') {
     $('#div2').show();
 }else{
     $('#div1').hide();
     $('#div2').hide(); 
 }

};
```

Aquí agrego **[el ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/yoh8brcd/2/)**.